# Guardar valores de una matriz Java

Tags: java

Buenas tardes tengo el siguiente codigo de un proyecto de la universidad, mi duda es como hago para guardar los valores de una matriz que va editando el usuario y que al final los muestre, el proyecto es reservar asientos.Donde llama al metodo lo tengo en un switch porque tengo que mostrar un menu antes de entrar aca, pero si el usario quiere volver a digitar los mismos valores de antes igual los registra.

Tengo lo siguiente

```
        System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de asientos que desea reservar: ");
    cantidadAsientosUsuario = sc.nextInt();
    for(int i = 1 ; i <= cantidadAsientosUsuario ; i++)
    { // Inicio for
        while(cantidadAsientosUsuario <= 0)
        { // Inicio while
            System.out.println("Favor ingresar una cantidad de asientos correcta: ");
            cantidadAsientosUsuario = sc.nextInt();
        } // Fin WHILE.


        System.out.println("Favor ingresar el numero de fila (1-5)");
        filaTeatro = sc.nextInt();
        while(filaTeatro < 1 || filaTeatro > 5)
        { // Inicio WHILE.
            System.out.println("INCORRECTO.\nFavor ingresar el numero de fila (1-5)");
            filaTeatro = sc.nextInt();

        } // Fin WHILE.


        System.out.println("Favor ingresar el numero de columna(1-22)");
        columnaTeatro = sc.nextInt();
        while(columnaTeatro < 1 || columnaTeatro > 22)
        { // Inicio WHILE.
            System.out.println("INCORRECTO.\nFavor ingresar el numero de columna(1-22)");
            columnaTeatro = sc.nextInt();
        } // Fin WHILE.


        if(matriz[filaTeatro - 1][columnaTeatro - 1] == 'E')
        { // If
            System.out.println("LATERAL IZQUIERDA\nReserva exitosa");
            matriz[filaTeatro - 1][columnaTeatro - 1] = 'R';


        } // If

        else if(matriz[filaTeatro - 1][columnaTeatro - 1] == 'D')

        { // Inicio ELSE IF.

            System.out.println("LATERAL DERECHA\nReserva exitosa");
            matriz[filaTeatro - 1][columnaTeatro - 1] = 'R';

        } // Fin ELSE IF.

        else if(matriz[filaTeatro - 1][columnaTeatro - 1] == 'O')
        { // Inicio ELSE IF.
            System.out.println("Asiento ocupado.");
        } // Fin ELSE IF.
        else if(matriz[filaTeatro - 1][columnaTeatro - 1] == 'P')
        {
            System.out.println("Disculpe, este asiento es un pasillo.");
```

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que quieres conseguir. Vas a tener que explicarte mejor. De momento te diré que el `while` en el que compruebas que el número de asientos sea mayor que cero, el primero dentro del `for`, no tiene sentido porque si introdujo `0`, nunca va a entrar en el `for` que es donde compruebas eso.

Comment: Comparto el comentario de @superG280 tampoco termino de entender lo que quieres. Deberias hacer una exception, poniendo, que si la entrada es igual a 0, que muestre un mensaje de "No puedes elegir 0 asientos". No muestras la creacion del array, pero en Java, no deberias tener mas problemas que hacer un push con el dato recibido. Tambien te recomendaria hacer try catch, ya que si en filaTeatro, introduces caracteres, rompera la ejecucion.

Comment: Hola Keylor trata de explicar que es lo que deseas para que de esa forma la comunidad pueda apoyarte, revisar [ask], saludos.